# How many objects can LINQ used to create per second?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, stress-testing

I used Linq to insert objects into database.But if i used threads to simultanously create 20 object within 1 second, then system will fail to add 20 objects into database.

And I found it is not because of the sql server 's limit. so the only possible is Linq, any one have idea ? How can I create 20 records or more in 1 second within 1 second ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the system will fail"? Error message, do the records just not show up in the database, does the creation of the 20 records take longer than 1 second...?

Comment: On my totally paralleled imaginary super computer, LINQ can create an infinite number of objects per second. Or. What was the question? I guess the answer is, in best Raymond Chen style, if you have to ask for a limit, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I just don't know why I send 20 request per second to create 20 objects, but finally it only created 6 objects. so there must be something wrong and throw away the requests which cause this problem, anyone have ideas ?

Comment: Now that I think about it, isn't LINQ to SQL supposed to query data, rather than update data? How are you inserting the objects into the data base? Maybe some code will help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you are using threads to insert 20 records into your database. If you are using the same database context, this could be your problem. I don't believe the L2S database context object is thread safe.